# How do I calculate the overall accuracy

Tags: ml

I have the accuracy of each class of a specific data set.

for 8 classes are: 94.97- 98.55- 61.54- 55.73- 53.98- 97.05- 1.14- 98.54

how can I calculate the overall accuracy for this data?

Comment: Just apply the formula. What have you tried? What is your problem?

Comment: These are the accuracy of each classes for example class A has 99.97 accuracy.

Comment: I wanna calculate the overall accuracy. is it true that I calculate the average of them?